# Rails invite friend from facebook to application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am creating a website application which is running in rails. It currently use devise for authentication and has many field that a user has to have before they can register, i also implemented confirmable in order to verify their email is correct.

Now the issue is i am trying to allow user once created to invite friend on facebook to come to my application. That is where i am a bit confused, if i implement the idea of this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview, then the idea is that you either sign in with devise or with facebook, and if you are just as a user then you can't invite your friends.

How can i change this logic, i am looking for a simple way to login with either devise and facebook but in both view to allow user to either enter their own credential for facebook or use the one provided and to invite friends. how can this be done in rails.

Any hint, tips or tutorial links would be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: If the user doesn't authenticate using Facebook in the first place, then there's no way for you to invite his/her Facebook 'friends'. What we've done is after a user signs up using email, add a button somewhere that says something like 'Connect your Facebook account' and proceed from there.

Comment: That what I would be looking into, would i be implementing devise ominauth or just ominauth at that point?

Comment: Well, to give you an idea, we use all of `devise`, `omniauth`, `omniauth-facebook` and `koala` (for fetching user profile details, etc.) gems. We created an `authentications_controller` to handle OAuth callback/redirects from Facebook—this would also create the user (if logging in for the first time) and store the OAuth tokens for that user in the database ('attaching' them to the existing user record, if ever), and so on.